# Is there a pre-iOS 4 replacement or workaround for UINib?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, ios4, nib

My application features a tableview which contains some rather complex tableviewcells. Therefore, these cells have been designed in Interface Builder and are instanciated later as needed using UINib which allows just that - load the content from a nib and instanciate it as needed.

But UINib is only available for iOS 4.0 and above.
Before I go ahead and abandon all the 3.x users, is there a way to (easily) recreate what I'm doing using pre-iOS4 classes and methods?

Thanks alot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load views from a nib using the following:

```
NSArray* nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyNibFilename" owner:self options:nil];
UITableViewCell* cell = (UITableViewCell*)[nibContents objectAtIndex:0];
```

Note that the index you supply to `objectAtIndex:` is determined by the order of the views in the nib.  If the only thing in the nib is your custom table view cell, then 0 is likely the correct index.

EDIT:

It is a [documented UIKit addition](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBundle_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html) to NSBundle.

Comment: You're right! Thanks! Do you happen to know where this method is being defined? The NSBundle class reference doesn't mention loadNibNamed at all.. thanks again!

Comment: `-[NSBundle loadNibNamed:owner:options:]` is declared in `UINibLoading.h`.